# WORDPRESS: Which is fast multiple get_user_meta or custom query to fetch record?

Tags: wordpress

I have created the function to get all data of admin information in one shot.

```php
function get_admin_meta($admin_user_id){
    
    $admin_user_meta        =   array();
    
    $admin_info =   get_userdata( $admin_user_id );
    
    $admin_user_meta['id']              =   (string)$admin_user_id;
    $admin_user_meta['phone_number']                =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'phone_number', true);
    $admin_user_meta['truck_owner']         =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'first_name', true);
    $admin_user_meta['full_name']           =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'first_name', true).' '.get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'last_name', true);
    $admin_user_meta['address']     =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'address', true);    
    $admin_user_meta['city']                =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'city', true);
    $admin_user_meta['date_of_activation']  =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'date_of_activation', true);
    $admin_user_meta['payment_amount']      =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'payment_amount', true);
    $admin_user_meta['next_due_after']      =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'next_due_after', true);
    $admin_user_meta['status']      =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'status', true);
    
    $admin_user_meta['insurance_validity']      =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'insurance_validity', true);
    $admin_user_meta['license_no']      =   get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'license_no', true);
    
    $admin_user_meta['profile_pic']     =   '';
    $admin_user_meta['license_pic']='';
    $licensePic=get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'license_pic', true);
    if(!empty($licensePic)){
      $admin_user_meta['license_pic']       =   get_template_directory_uri().'/images/user/'.$admin_user_id.'/license/'.$licensePic;
    }
    $profilePic=get_user_meta ($admin_user_id, 'profile_pic', true);
    if(!empty($profilePic)){
      $admin_user_meta['profile_pic']       =   get_template_directory_uri().'/images/user/'.$admin_user_id.'/profile/'.$profilePic;
    } 
    
    return $admin_user_meta;
}
```

or should I user query

```php
function get_admin_meta($admin_user_id){
    
    $admin_user_meta        =   array();
    
    //Query
    SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta where user_id=168 and meta_key in ("first_name","last_name","address","city","profile_pic","phone_number","zip_code"); 
    
    //loop fetch data into array with its value
    
    
    //return the association array 
    return $admin_user_meta;
}
```

Which one is the best method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say :

```
$adminMeta = get_user_meta($admin_user_id);
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

meta key is optionnal ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest solution would be to go the path of

```
$userMeta = get_user_meta(168);
```

according to wordpress documentation (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta see section "Examples" >> "Getting all meta data")

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct - you can call `get_user_meta` without a key to retrieve it in one blow, I just wanted to also point out that `get_user_meta` is cached so your method will not have a harmful effect on performance (WP will only hit the database the first time you access the user metadata, when you get the other keys it will just pull the data from its cache)